# spark dataframe to Bigquery using simba driver

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, spark-jdbc

While trying to write a dataframe to Bigquery using Simba driver. am getting the below exception.below is the dataframe. Have created a table in bigquery with same schema.

```
df.printSchema
root
 |-- empid: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- middle: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: double (nullable = true)
 |-- weight: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
```

Simba driver is throwing the below error

```
 Caused by: com.simba.googlebigquery.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: 400 Bad Request
    {
      "code" : 400,
      "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "location" : "q",
        "locationType" : "parameter",
        "message" : "Syntax error: Unexpected string literal \"empid\" at [1:38]",
        "reason" : "invalidQuery"
      } ],
      "message" : "Syntax error: Unexpected string literal \"empid\" at [1:38]",
      "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
      ... 24 more
```

below is the code am using for the same :

```
val url = "jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2;ProjectId=my_project_id;OAuthType=0;OAuthPvtKeyPath=service_account_jsonfile;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=googleaccount"
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url,"orders_dataset.employee",new java.util.Properties)
```

Please let me know if am missing any other configuration or where am going wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that behavior is caused by Spark, which is sending extra quotas around [column names](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialects.scala#L90).

To fix this behavior in Spark, you need to add the following code after creating Spark context and before create a dataframe:

```
JdbcDialects.registerDialect(new JdbcDialect() {

override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.toLowerCase.startsWith("jdbc:bigquery:")

override

def quoteIdentifier(column: String): String =  column

})
```